# How to add/remove images using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to add and remove images contained in divs based on if they are locked or unlocked.  Any divs that are unlocked are emptied and a new image is added accordingly.

```
function dieClicked(){
    console.log(this); 
    if (this.locked == true){
        this.locked = !this.locked;
        $(this).css("border-bottom", "none");
    }
    else{
        this.locked = !this.locked;
        $(".pics").each(function(){
            if (this.locked == true){
                $(this).css("border-bottom", "solid red 5px");
            }
        });
    }
}


function swapUnlocked(){ 
    $(".pics").each(function(){
        if (this.locked == false){
            $(this).empty();
            $(this).append("<img src='style/images/dice.png'/>")
        }
    });
}
```

Both of these functions are called in the main as follows:

```
$("#newRoll").on("click", swapUnlocked);
$(".pics").on("click",dieClicked);
```

newRoll is the id for a button, and .pics is the class that all of the divs belong to.  Upon clicking a div in the .pics class, a red border will appear and the div will be locked.  If the same div is clicked again, the border disappears and it is now unlocked.

When this code is executed, an image will switch as intended when it has been locked and then unlocked via the dieClicked function.  However, when some or all of the divs have not been clicked (they are not locked or unlocked) those images do not switch, ie. they are treated as if they are locked.  How can I get the images that have not been clicked to be treated as if they were unlocked?

Comment: Just .show() and .hide() the divs

Comment: @mplungjan i still need the locked divs to show up, and the locked divs must retain their image.  could you possibly elaborate how this might accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the lock value:

`$(".pics").on("click",dieClicked).each(function() { this.locked = false; });`

---

ETA: Have you considered using CSS? You can streamline your code a bit and it would also help keep your styles centralized:

CSS

```
.locked { border-bottom: solid red 5px; }
```

JS

```
function dieClicked(){
    $(this).toggleClass("locked");
}


function swapUnlocked(){ 
    $(".pics:not(.locked)").each(function(){
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).append("<img src='style/images/dice.png'/>");
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you. I had been trying to initialize the lock value. I just wasn't sure how to accomplish this!

Comment: This is for a final assignment in which the css and html were completed for the last submission.  We have been instructed to leave the css and html and make changes using jquery and javascipt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if you mean that:

```
function dieClicked(){
console.log(this); 
if (this.locked == true){
    this.locked = !this.locked;
    $(this).css("border-bottom", "none");
    //$(this).remove(); //to delete
    //$(this).hide(); //to hide -> can be shown with calling .show() on object
}
else{
    this.locked = !this.locked;
    $(".pics").each(function(){
        if (this.locked == true){
            $(this).css("border-bottom", "solid red 5px");
            //$(this).show();
        }
    });
}
}
function swapUnlocked(){ 
$(".pics").each(function(){
    if (this.locked == false){
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).append("<img src='style/images/dice.png'/>");
        this.locked = true;
    }
});
}
```